# Python PyGame delay

Tags: python, pygame, delay

I have a function like this:

```
  def valami() :
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 20, 20)) 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (100, 100, 120, 120)) 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (200, 200, 220, 220))
```

And this is my main while loop:

```
  while True:
        valami()
```

I want to draw these 3 rectangles one by one every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an array of rectangles and a counter:

```py
rects = [(0, 0, 20, 20), (100, 100, 120, 120), (200, 200, 220, 220)]
counter = 0
```

Draw the rectangle dependent on `counter` in `valami`:

```py
def valami() :
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), rects[counter % len(rects)])
```

Define a user event see ([`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)) and start a timer with an interval of 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds) before the main loop, See [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer):

```py
mytimerevent = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(mytimerevent, 5000) # 5000 milliseconds
```

Increment `counter` when the timer elapse. A timer can be stopped by calling [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) with an interval of 0:

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == mytimerevent: # timer event
            counter += 1
            if counter == 2:
                pygame.time.set_timer(mytimerevent, 0) # stop timer

    screen.fill(0)
    valami()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Note, the modulom (`%`) operator calculates the rest (remainder) of an integral division.
Because of `rects[counter % len(rects)]` the rectangles will be drawn on by one in a loop, if you don't stop the timer.

Comment: I've worked it out a little bit, but it worked. Thanks a lot :)